# switchMap can not read value of undefined

Tags: angular

I am working with switchMap and I am gettinf following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchMap' of undefined
>       at StartComponent.push../src/app/start/start.component.ts.StartComponent.updateShortUrl
>   (start.component.ts:81)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (StartComponent.html:19)
>       at handleEvent (core.js:10258)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11054)
>       at dispatchEvent (core.js:7717)
>       at core.js:8161
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (platform-browser.js:995)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3815)

Whats wrong here?

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      first: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.regUrl)]],
      second: ['', [Validators.maxLength(6), Validators.pattern(this.regAlias)]],
      domainForm: [{ value: this.baseUrl, disabled: true }]
    });
  }
 this.form.value.valueChanges.switchMap(item =>
      this.urlService.update(this.data, key)
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      //this.infoUrlWasCreated();
      this.loading = false;
    });
```

Comment: `this.form.value.valueChanges` does not exist, or is undefined. Can you post more of your code to highlight where you are defining this variable?

Comment: ok, I have also import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: That's not the problem in the error Noah, it's not failing to find `switchMap`, it is failing to find `this.form.value.valueChanges` (it is undefined)

Comment: Ok, I could also use this.urlShortenerForm.get('first').value or this.urlShortenerForm.get('first').valueChanges but also not working but I am getting the value

Answer (score 0):

As Christian said in the comments, you're using an undefined subscription. According to [Angular API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup), the correct way to use it is

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
   // ...
});
```